# WPF - How can I use an ObservableCollection of viewmodels to show TabItems?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a window which contains a TabControl and I would like to have TabItems generated based on user actions. Inside the TabItems I would like to display a UserControl which uses a ViewModel.

I can get everything to display properly, however when the UserControl's ViewModel is updated, the changes are not reflected in the TabItem.

Consider the following simplified example:

**MainWindowViewModel.cs**

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModel
{
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        MyControls = new ObservableCollection<MyControlViewModel>();
    }

    private ObservableCollection<MyControlViewModel> _myControls;
    public ObservableCollection<MyControlViewModel> MyControls
    {
        get { return _myControls; }
        set
        {
            _myControls = value;
            RaisePropertyChangedEvent(nameof(MyControls));
        }
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private static MainWindowViewModel _vm;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
        _vm = DataContext as MainWindowViewModel;

        var myItem1 = new MyItem("Item1");
        var myItem2 = new MyItem("Item2");

        var myControlVm = new MyControlViewModel(new ObservableCollection<MyItem> { myItem1, myItem2 });

        _vm.MyControls.Add(myControlVm);
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="TabControlTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TabControlTest"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainWindowViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyControls}">
            <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MyControlViewModel}">
                    <local:MyControl />
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MyControlViewModel.cs**

```
public class MyControlViewModel : ViewModel
{
    public MyControlViewModel(ObservableCollection<MyItem> items)
    {
        MyItems = items;
    }

    private ObservableCollection<MyItem> _myItems;
    public ObservableCollection<MyItem> MyItems
    {
        get { return _myItems; }
        set
        {
            _myItems = value;
            RaisePropertyChangedEvent(nameof(MyItems));
        }
    }
}
```

**MyControl.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MyControl : UserControl
{
    public MyControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ListBox_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var vm = DataContext as MyControlViewModel;

        foreach (var item in vm.MyItems)
        {
            item.ShouldBold = !item.ShouldBold;
        }
    }
}
```

**MyControl.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="TabControlTest.MyControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TabControlTest"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}" MouseDoubleClick="ListBox_MouseDoubleClick">
            <ListBox.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                    <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding Label}" />
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ShouldBold}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ListBox.Resources>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**MyItem.cs**

```
public class MyItem : ViewModel
{
    public MyItem(string label)
    {
        Label = label;
    }

    private string _label;
    public string Label
    {
        get { return _label; }
        set
        {
            _label = value;
            RaisePropertyChangedEvent(nameof(Label));
        }
    }

    private bool _shouldBold;
    public bool ShouldBold
    {
        get { return _shouldBold; }
        set
        {
            _shouldBold = value;
            RaisePropertyChangedEvent(nameof(ShouldBold));
        }
    }
}
```

When I double-click on the `MyControl` in the MainWindow I would expect the items to be displayed in bold via the `ListBox_MouseDoubleClick` method, however the style is not applying. When I step through the `ListBox_MouseDoubleClick` method, I can see that the `ShouldBold` is being updated correctly, but again the style is not applying.

Is there another way I should structure this or something else I need to do to have the style apply? Any help is appreciated!

**Edit**

Here's my **ViewModel.cs**

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChangedEvent(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Comment: While the code you provided is a reasonably concise example, when I compiled and ran the code, it works exactly as you want it to. The items in the list box change displayed from not bold to bold when the list box is double-clicked. If you want help, please provide a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem you are asking about. And as you construct that example, please make sure that the complications such as the user control and the tab control are in fact required to reproduce the issue, to ensure your code example is in fact as **minimal** as possible.

Comment: @rhowe: How is the `ViewModel` base class implemented?

Comment: @mm8: I added my ```ViewModel``` above.

Comment: @rhowe: You don't implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `ViewModel` class should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
...
```